# Install Oracle Java JRE 7 on Ubuntu with just the command line

Tags: java, installation, oracle

- I can't use openjdk because it doesn't have native .jpg support.
- I can't use `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin` any more because apparently those have been pulled.
- JRE version 7 works, but the only way I've found to get it is to accept the terms of service ON THEIR WEBSITE and I need to install Java ON MY SERVER where I only have command line access.

Throw me a fricken bone here Java!

**Edit**

It just dawned on me that I can download the .tar.gz on my desktop computer and scp it over to the server. Who put me in charge?!

Answer (score 2):

Just download the tarball and then install it. On a Debian or Ubuntu system I would install it to /usr/lib/jvm/XXX and run update-alternatives:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
tar -xzf /path/to/java_tarball.tar.gz
update-alternatives --remove-all java
update-alternatives --remove-all javac
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/YOURJAVA/bin/java 1000
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/YOURJAVA/bin/javac 1000
```

You don't have to run the --remove-all part, in that case make sure the number "1000" is higher than the current one it's set to, which can be found with:

```
update-alternatives --display java (or javac)
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to install the Oracle JDK and the Oracle JRE and receive software updates of those packages is by add a repository with installation packages to our system with those instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-8-oracle
```

Reference:

https://www.leggiero.uk/posts/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-and-keep-updated/

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to accept license and download the tar from command line, all in one step.

You can pass a cookie to the server via `wget` in this way:

```
wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u51-b16/jdk-8u51-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

After that you can just install the tar by extracting and updating alternatives as in @aseq answer above.

*Note: Make sure that accepting the license in this way is legal, before using this method.*

*Note: Name of cookie and its value might change in time.*